# How can I make PHPMailer work on BlueHost?

Tags: php, phpmailer

PHPMailer works well on GoDaddy and on my localhost; however, it doesn't work on Bluehost.  I have tried everything.  At the beginning it did partially work, i.e., it sent an email and I could activate the account, but I couldn't login.  However, now it just shows a blank page or it shows a waiting sign.   When it did partially work the `$mail->SMTPDebug  = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;`  gave  a  detailed report; however, I couldn't see any error in it.  Now the browser simply shows a blank page or a waiting sign.  Bluehost error_log file shows: 
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'SMTP' not found in/home4/username/public_html/vendor_email.php:23`

Here is my code:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
//use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    // Load Composer's autoloader
    require './vendor/autoload.php';
    //require './classes/Config.php';

function send_email($email=null, $subject=null, $message=null, $header=null) {

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {

//Server Settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;  
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                     
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = true;   
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  
    $mail->Host       = 'mail.mywebsite.com'; 
    $mail->Port       = ' 465'; 
    $mail->Username   = 'autoreply@mywebsite.com';                    
    $mail->Password   = 'secret'; 

   //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('autoreply@mywebsite.com');
    $mail->addAddress($email); 

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message; 

 $mail->send();
 echo 'Message has been sent';
  } catch (Exception $e) {
 echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
}
```

I varied this code to multiple settings similar to what is posted on Stackoverflow, YouTube, and to my settings at GoDaddy.  Also, I reinstalled composer and updated PHPMailer from 6.0 to the latest version 6.5; however, nothing works.

Comment: as your logs giving the hint that `not found in/home4/username/public_html/vendor_email.php` not found, please visit the lib dir and check are you really missing this file or php is not able to read it

Comment: What is the version of PHP you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

change `tls` to `ssl` when using port `465`.

[Read more about PHPMailer troubleshooting wiki here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#encryption-flavours)

Additionally the use of authentication is required , you need to remove comments on

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
```

Comment: I have already tried `ssl` and `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;`  But it didn't work.  Browser showed a waiting sign and then timed out.  I wanted to try these again, but the browser shows the following message: `Not Acceptable!
An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.`

Comment: It seems ```mod_security``` is blocking some requests. There are possible number of reasons, either cookies are disable on your side (which I doubt) , or some post filters are being block. Disable ```SecFilterEngine``` and  ```SecFilterScanPOST```  in your ```htaccess``` file if you have one.

Comment: I typed the following code on htaccess `<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>`  But still I am getting the same message in the browser.

Comment: It is becoming worse and worse.  First, it partially worked. Then it stopped working and just showed a blank page or a waiting sign.  Now, I am getting this error message in the browser.

Comment: which error are you getting now. clear browser cookies and cache and retry or probably switch to a new browser

Comment: I have tried those, but not with the current error.  I did also clear Windows 10 cache and flushed DNS, and restarted my computer.  But it didn't work.  My `.htaccess` has been rewritten by Bluehost technician to enable SSL.  My default cPanel doen't have a button for manually disabling mod security.

Comment: does the default ```mail``` function works? If you haven't give that too a try

Comment: Do you mean php mail function?  I haven't tried that because it doesn't show emails in html format.

Comment: I restarted my computer and after trying to register in my website, I've got the following error: `2020-05-23 19:56:32 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`

Comment: that looks like a network error. check if internet connectiviity is ok

Comment: the PHP mail function can handle html formatted message. just design them or use a template. The disadvantage is, your message might always land in spam box

Comment: My internet connection is good.   But I may give PHP mail function a try at least as a temporary fix.  Thanks!

Comment: PHPMailer sends messages in HTML if you like, and if you comment out the call to `isSMTP()`, it will send them using `mail()`.